# Magento2 error "The time value is using an unsupported format. Enter a supported format and try again"

Tags: magento, report, magento2, magento-2.3, magento2.4

I have an issue while setup/configuring Advanced Reporting. "The time value is using an unsupported format. Enter a supported format and try again." this error occurred while configuring Advanced Reporting and "Time of day to send data"  shows only hours and minutes configuration. I really appreciate any help you can provide. Thanks in advance.

[image: 1]

I want to setup BI Report/ Advanced Report in magento 2.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade Magento 2.4 to 2.4.4-p2 resolve my issue.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for answering. But it's working fine on another website which have same version of magento